# Android. Как на BroadcastReceiver поставить счетчик запусков в Service, который его запустил?

Tags: android, service, broadcast-receiver

Есть класс `LocationTracker extends BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class LocationTracker extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //someTask();
        int schetchik++;
    }
}
```

его запускает alarmManager раз в 5 минут из класса `ForegroundService extends Service` следующим кодом

```
int schetchik;        

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(ForegroundService.this, LocationTracker.class);    
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);    
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ForegroundService.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);    
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(),LocationProvider.FIVE_MINUTES, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Я бы очень хотел чтоб при каждом запуске BroadcastReceiver по будильнику оповещал ForegroundService и увеличивал в нем счетчик на единицу. Как это сделать?

Интуитивно чувствую, что проблема должна решатся с помощью `createPendingResult`, чтоб ресивер по команде `send` оповещал мой `Service` о том что ресивер был запущен, но ума не приложу как это сделать.

Comment: можно вести счетчик в SharedPreferences

Comment: Нет нельзя, потому что запускается несколько раз BroadcastReceiver, а Service только при создании.

Comment: А если служба перезапущена?)

Comment: Если служба перезапущена то будильни к обнуляется.

Comment: Ммм, тогда у вас вопрос некорректен

Comment: А на какой исправить?

Answer (score 1):

МОжно использовать SharedPreferences.

```
public void addCount() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("key", getCount() + 1);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int key = sp.getInt("key", 0);
        return key;
    }
```

В Вашем BroadCast вызывайте addCount. в Service же getCount по необходимости.

Comment: Это в службе дополнительный таймер надо делать чтоб SharedPreferences проверял раз в 5 минут, некрасиво(

Comment: а какой вы собрались там счетчик увеличивать? и как его проверять планировали и почему именно там?

Comment: Там потому что так надо, не собирался и не планировал, сразу решил спросить у людей которые знают как это сделать.

Comment: =) Так а почему вы тогда решили, что ваша задача поставлена правильно?

Comment: Разразитесь аргументами в пользу её не правильности) Я весь во внимании)

Comment: Так ответьте тогда, где в вашем Service этот "счетчик" должен увеличиваться именно и для каких целей? Как вы его собираетесь его использовать внутри этого вашего Service?

Comment: "Где?" -хоть где."Для каких целей?" для целей подсчета срабатываний ресивера. "Как использовать?" - отключать сервис и будильник по значению счетчика.

Comment: Так а чем мое решение не подходит?=))))

Comment: в ресивере смотрите сколько getCount(), если он еще не достиг вашего нужного количества, то вызываете addCount. Если же достиг- то останавливаете службу.

Comment: Да, решение грубое, но действенное, так и сделаю. Спасибо!